# Google VR SDK for Unity - Reticle not aligned

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr

I've been working with the Google VR SDK for Unity but I've run in to some weird issues with adding a reticle, specifically using the GoogleVR prefab GvrReticle.  Up until a couple weeks ago the reticle was lined up and looking fine in my projects but now I can't seem to get the reticle to work properly, both installed on device(iPhone or Android) or in the Unity preview mode.  It appears slightly misaligned so that when you wear the device in it's headset you will get two dots instead of one reticle.
[image: headsetdemo]
[image: sample cubes]

Even in a sample project that just includes the SDK and the barebones necessary for a reticle the result is the same(a double-vision reticle).

Has anyone else run into this problem or would know what might possibly be causing it?

I'm using the latest versions Unity(5.4.1f1) and googleVR(unity sdk v0.9.1) and I've tried doing builds on both PC and Mac with seemingly the same results. I've uploaded a sample project here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64965870/ReticleSample.zip

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, solved with the new GoogleVR SDK Ver 1.10 (https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk)

try and replacing the current SDK with the newest, it's pretty easy to replace.